# How to save Toggle Button's "on/off" mode on Page Refresh for website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use the [W3Schools Toggle Switch](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch) for my website Dark/Light Mode Toggle.

This is my [Website Test Page](https://freeairdrop.io/airdrop/bannertest2.html) in which I have added the Toggle Switch but the thing which happens is that the switch is not able to save it's "on/off" mode when the page is refreshed.

It restores back to it's default "Off" mode when I refresh the Page.

How can I save it's position on Page Refresh?

Comment: try localStorage

Comment: Can you please share the code for "localStorage" that will be used in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First update below code on "// On page load se the theme." section

```
var tSwitcher = document.getElementById('theme-switcher');
let element = document.body;

let onpageLoad = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "";
if(onpageLoad != null && onpageLoad  == 'dark-mode'){
  tSwitcher.checked = true;
} 
element.classList.add(onpageLoad);


function themeToggle(){
  if(tSwitcher.checked){
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-mode');
        element.classList.add('dark-mode');
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', '');
        element.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    }
}
```

and change

```
<input type="checkbox"  onclick="themeToggle()">

to 

<input type="checkbox"  onclick="themeToggle()" id="theme-switcher">
```

Comment: Thanks @Libin Prasanth I will just change it.

Comment: I think you removed the themeToggle() function from your code, let's keep that function

Comment: Can you please share the complete script for that?

Answer (score 0):

you can store the status of toggle (on or off into localstorage) and get the value from localstorage.

Comment: Can you please share the code for "localStorage" that will be used in my case? @Ashish